# Ag grid excel export override line number and column labels font size

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

When I am attempting to export data to excel using ag grid enterprise, data font is being modified in accordance to excelStyle, however the row and column labels remain as Calibri 14pt,Is there a way to override this?

Comment: What effort did you do to accomplish that ? thanks